# Box2D bodies order inside the world

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm working on a small platform game using box2d.
When I create the game's objects I store them inside a vector. One for dynamic bodies and one for static bodies.

```
auto static_obj = Factory<StaticObject>::create(name, position, world);
auto dynamic_obj = Factory<DynamicObject>::create(name, position, world);

if (static_obj)
    static_objects.push_back(std::move(static_obj));
else if (dynamic_obj)
    dynamic_objects.push_back(std::move(dynamic_obj));
```

Afterwards when the game starts I have to pull the dynamic bodies from the world and update the visual part of the objects.

```
for (b2Body* BodyIterator = m_world->GetBodyList(); BodyIterator != 0; BodyIterator = BodyIterator->GetNext())
{

    if (BodyIterator->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody || BodyIterator->GetType() == b2_kinematicBody)
    {
        auto data = (GameObject*)BodyIterator->GetUserData().pointer;

        if (data)
        {
            if (data->get_name() == "moving_platform")
            {

                m_dynamic_objects[counter]->update_position(SCALE * BodyIterator->GetPosition().x - 16, SCALE * BodyIterator->GetPosition().y - 25);
                m_dynamic_objects[counter]->update_rotation(BodyIterator->GetAngle() * 180 / b2_pi);

                counter++;
            }
            else if (data->get_name() == "player")
            {
                m_dynamic_objects[counter]->update_position(SCALE * BodyIterator->GetPosition().x, SCALE * BodyIterator->GetPosition().y);
                m_dynamic_objects[counter]->update_rotation(BodyIterator->GetAngle() * 180 / b2_pi);
                counter++;
            }
        }
}
```

But the problem is that there is no synchronization between the order of the objects in the world and their order in the vector.

Is there any order of objects within the world or is it just random? And if so, how can my problem be addressed?

Comment: Have you try to use a structure to memorize the association between your objects and the bodies? Either a custom one or a standard one such as std::map or anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

I founded very simple solution. For each object I'm holding the body, so there is no need to go through the body list of the world, but just let every object to update his own position by taking the position from the body.

```
this->update_position(SCALE * m_phisical_body->GetPosition().x, SCALE * m_phisical_body->GetPosition().y);
```